# Is this quotient space of a square a Möbius strip?

Tags: general-topology

Considering a square $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with vertices $(0,0),(0,1),(1,0),(1,1)$, what is the quotient space $X/\sim$ where $(x,1)\sim (1,1-x)$ for $0<x<1$, and $(1,0)\sim (0,1) \sim (1,1)$, and finally $y\sim y$  for $y$ in $X$ otherwise. I'm trying to classify all quotient spaces that arise when identifying only edges to edges.

I've been playing around with it and I'm pretty sure it's homeomorphic to a Möbius strip by the reasoning in the attached photo:[image]

Is this thinking correct or do I need some help? (For context this is my first semester of topology so higher methods might need more explaining if used. Thx.)

Comment: It's correct. But you should ask your professor if they want to see more details in the proof

Comment: Okay thank you. I'll accept this as an answer.